# How to retrieve data from file with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have added a JSON-file to my file-system where the data is structured like this:

> { "DDD" : "3D Systems Corporation", "MMM" : "3M Company", "WBAI" :
>   "500.com Limited", "WUBA" : "58.com Inc.", "AHC" : "A.H. Belo
>   Corporation", "ATEN" : "A10 Networks, Inc.", "AAC" : "AAC Holdings,
>   Inc.", "AIR" : "AAR Corp." }

my file-name is `stockDict.json` and I'm trying to retrieve the data from it by using this code:

```
let jsonFilePath:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("stockDict", ofType: "json")!
        let jsonData:NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(jsonFilePath as String) as! NSData
        let error:NSError?
        let json = JSON(jsonData)

        println(json[0][0].string)
```

But all I get when it prints is `nil`. What is wrong with my code?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this answer to be very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/28644494/535339

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try with

```
let json = JSON(data: jsonData) // Note: data: parameter name
println(json["DDD"].string)
```

Comment: Now I have, and it still prints "nil".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The question is about loading JSON from a file.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3/4 version:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "JSON", ofType: "json")!
let jsonString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let json = JSON(parseJSON: jsonString!)
```

Comment: Nowadays it is recommended to use Bundle.main.url instead of Bundle.main.path.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the rep to comment, but this answer is deprecated as of iOS 8, specifically the following part.

```
.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile
```

XCode is telling me.

```
'dataWithContentsOfMappedFile' was deprecated in iOS 8.0: Use +dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: and NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe or NSDataReadingMappedAlways instead.
```

------EDIT--------

Here is the updated code I am using.  It compiles and runs with a target of iOS 9.1.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "json")
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path!)
let json = JSON(data: jsonData!)
```