# Read JSON data from file Swift 2.0 works on simulator but not on device, return json null

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift2, swifty-json

Hello I'm trying to write and read some data JSON format from file in my app.
I know that on device filename is key sensitive and i checked it twice. My problem is to understand why it works fine on simulator and return null JSON data on device.Thank you a lot!

```
func writeJsonData() {

    let file = "/settings.json"
    if let dir :  NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
        let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
            let json =  ["val1":1, "val2":2]
            self.jsonToNSData(json)
            if let file = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath:path) {
                file.writeData(jsonToNSData(json)!)
        }
    }

    self.readJsonData()
}

func readJsonData () {

    let file = "/settings.json"
    if let dir :  NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
        let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            print(json)  // !!!!!!!!!!!
            if json != JSON.null {

                let val1 = json["val1"].int!
                let val2 = json["val2"].int!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is in writing data, the corect way is:

```
func writeJsonData() {
        let file = "file.json"
        if let dir :  NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
            let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
                let json: JSON =  ["val1":val1 as Int, "val2":val2 as Int]
                let str = json.description
                let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                if let file = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath:path) {
                    file.writeData(data)
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`let file = "/settings.json"` is not going to work on the device.

You need to look at `NSBundle` (i'll update this post in a min or two when I can pull you some sample code)

I only have objective c code at the moment - but it should be the same:

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"org.mitre.EGM96GeoidCalculator"];
NSString *path2 = [myBundle pathForResource:@"EGM96" ofType:@""];
```

What you need to do in swift - etc is similar (see this post: [Reading in a JSON File Using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410881/reading-in-a-json-file-using-swift))

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "json")
{
    if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
    {
        if let jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let persons : NSArray = jsonResult["person"] as? NSArray
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Now if you are doing something in a framework - or what not you don't want to access `mainBundle` but rather the bundle with the identifier of the framework.

Comment: Thank you!! 
actually, i tried without slash, the problem is somewhere else i guess, because i am able to read data from mainBundle, and on simulator even to write data to the file in correct json format it works very fine, my problem is on a device. The writeJsonData function,  file.writeData() didn't return any errors. More, from mainBundle, i'm able to read data:
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("settings", ofType: "json")if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!) {let json = JSON(data: data) if json != JSON.null {//do stuff  }}

Comment: Again Thank you @Jeff, The problems was somehow in the file i just make o copy of the file and rename it (without changing nothing inside!!!) :O and it starts working fine on devices, i'm sorry for making you losing you time.
Thanks ;)