# How to read Json file from XCUITest?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, xcuitest

I've got a json file in my xcode project and I'm trying to read the file via:

```
let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myfile", withExtension: "json")
```

and so on.

When I run this code from a file within the project target membership like a view controller file, the code runs and I'm able to read the json. However, when run it within my XCUITestCase file – it fails, unable to find the url.

How can I read the json file from within XCUItest?

I've taken a look at this post which hasn't helped
[Read local JSON file in XCUITest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309402/read-local-json-file-in-xcuitest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a little modification of your code, and this works for me

```
if let file = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "YOUR_FILE", withExtension: "json") {
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: file)
    let dataJson = try! JSON(data: data)
    // TODO Your handle here
} else {
    XCTFail("Cannot read json file")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you know why Bundle(for: type(of: self)) allows for a correct url? I read that if the file is in the main target then Bundle.main should be used.

Comment: That's because the unit test is not a standalone app. With mainBundle you get something like /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools, but using bundleForClass gets you the bundle where your unit test class is located.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thank you. I appreciate you taking the time to help me learn and get better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this `myfile.json` to UITest target? This is the most common problem

Comment: yes I did. In the righthand panel under the paper icon, I selected the target membership to be both the project and the UITest.