# json not parsing properly

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

So I tried to parse a json file and when I parse it as per the syntax, it gives me an error that cannot change the string to an array of dictionary, but when I fix the problem, it generates `nil`. Can anyone give an opinion

```
func jsonFour() {
    let string = "[{\"address\": 7023000630,\"reportStatus\": \"Retrieved\",\"currentLocation\": {\"latitude\": 29.8529, \"longitude\": 73.99332,\"timestamp\": \"2019-01-07T16:35:25.079+05:30\"} }, {\"address\": 7290098339, \"reportStatus\": \"Retrieved\", \"currentLocation\": {\"latitude\": 21.628569, \"longitude\": 72.996956,\"timestamp\": \"2019-01-07T16:35:25.079+05:30\" } } ]"

    let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
    do {
        if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [[ String : Any ]]
        {
            print(jsonArray) // use the json here
            let address = jsonArray["address"] as! [[String:Any]]
            if let timestamp = address["timestamp"] as? [String]{print(timestamp)}
        } else {
            print("bad json")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

When I remove the double brackets from `"String : Any"`, it runs fine, but does not give any value but `nil`.

And when I proceed with this way, it skips the if statement and just prints `"bad json"`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet `jsonArray` is an `array` and array can't subscript a value of type `[[String: Any]]`, so instead you should parse like,

```
func jsonFour(){
    let string = "[{\"address\": 7023000630,\"reportStatus\": \"Retrieved\",\"currentLocation\": {\"latitude\": 29.8529, \"longitude\": 73.99332,\"timestamp\": \"2019-01-07T16:35:25.079+05:30\"} }, {\"address\": 7290098339, \"reportStatus\": \"Retrieved\", \"currentLocation\": {\"latitude\": 21.628569, \"longitude\": 72.996956,\"timestamp\": \"2019-01-07T16:35:25.079+05:30\" }}]"

    let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
    do {
        if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [[String: Any]]
        {
            print(jsonArray) // print the json here
            for jsonObj in jsonArray {
                if let dict = jsonObj as? [String: Any] {
                    if let address = dict["address"] {
                        print(address)
                    }
                    if let location = dict["currentLocation"] as? [String: Any], let timeStamp = location["timestamp"]  {
                        print(timeStamp)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("bad json")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is `Codable`, I would strongly recommend you to using it instead of `JSONSerialization`.

So start with declaring your structs to match with your JSON struct

```
struct Model: Codable {
    var address: Int
    var reportStatus: String
    var currentLocation: Location
}

struct Location: Codable {
    var latitude, longitude: Double
    var timestamp: String
}
```

Now just decode your JSON using `JSONDecoder`

```
do {
    let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
    let models = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

... now `models` is array of `Model` objects and you can work with it.

Answer (score 1):

For sure you should use `Codable` for this , but for your code to run use

```
let string = "[{\"address\": 7023000630,\"reportStatus\": \"Retrieved\",\"currentLocation\": {\"latitude\": 29.8529, \"longitude\": 73.99332,\"timestamp\": \"2019-01-07T16:35:25.079+05:30\"} }, {\"address\": 7290098339, \"reportStatus\": \"Retrieved\", \"currentLocation\": {\"latitude\": 21.628569, \"longitude\": 72.996956,\"timestamp\": \"2019-01-07T16:35:25.079+05:30\" } } ]"

let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[ String : Any ]]
    {
        jsonArray.forEach {

            if  let add = $0["address"] as? Int  , let currentLocation = $0["currentLocation"] as? [String:Any], let timestamp = currentLocation["timestamp"] as? String
            {
                print("address is : ", add ,"timestamp is : " , timestamp)
            }
        }

    } else {
        print("bad json")
    }
} catch  {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Your obvious problem is here

```
let address = jsonArray["address"] as! [[String:Any]]
```

`jsonArray` is an array that you can't subscript with `["address"]`

Answer (score 1):

An array is a list. It can contain multiple items. You have to use a loop to iterate an array (like in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089660/how-to-parse-json-data-from-local-files))

- The value for key `address` is `Int` (no double quotes).
- The value for key `timestamp` is `String` and is in the dictionary for key `currentLocation` in the array

  ```
  let data = Data(string.utf8)
  do {
      if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String : Any]]
      {
          print(jsonArray) // use the json here
          for item in array {
             let address = item["address"] as! Int
             let currentLocation = item["currentLocation"] as! [String:Any]
             let timestamp = currentLocation["timestamp"] as! String
             print(timestamp)
          }
      } else {
          print("bad json")
      }
  } catch {
      print(error)
  }
  ```

**Never use `.mutableContainers` in Swift. It's pointless.**