# How to read a (JSON or Txt or XMl or XML) file created in local xcode 9, Swift language 4

Tags: xcode, swift4

How to read any of the above mentioned file via Xcode in swift 4 language.

Comment: By doing some research.

Comment: You should be able to Google a solution to this. If after that you are still having issues you can post the problematic code and someone will probably be happy to help you debug and fix the issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to read a local .json file named "test.json":

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "json") {
    do {
          let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
          let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
          if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, let person = jsonResult["person"] as? [Any] {
                    // do stuff
          }
      } catch {
           // handle error
      }
}
```

Where "test" is the name of the file and "json" is type. You can replace ofType: argument to the type you want e.g. "txt", "xml".

Source: [Reading in a JSON File Using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410881/reading-in-a-json-file-using-swift#24411014)

Comment: just drag and drop it to your project.