# Fatal error: Failed to decode productsTest.json from app bundle

Tags: ios, json, swift

It stated `"Build Succeeded"`.
However, on the canvas, it stated `"Could not view this file - crashed"`. And the app crashed as well.

Problem from JSONDecoder.swift

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Failed to decode productsTest.json from app bundle.
```

**Content View (file name: ContentView.swift)**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let menu = Bundle.main.decode([ProductSection].self, from: "productsTest.json")
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            
            VStack{
                List {
                    ForEach(menu) { section in
                        Text(section.category)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Products")
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Codeable extension to decode json (file name: JSONDecoder.swift)**

```
extension Bundle {

    func decode<x: Decodable>(_ type: x.Type, from filename: String) -> x {
        guard let json = url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(filename) in app bundle.")
        }

        guard let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: json) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(filename) from app bundle.")
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        guard let result = try? decoder.decode(x.self, from: jsonData) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(filename) from app bundle.")
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

**Swift file to guide reading JSON (file name: ProductsTest.swift)**

```
struct ProductSection: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var category: String
    var items: [ItemList]
}

struct ItemList: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var status: String
    var quantity: Int
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var image: String
    var moreImage: [String]
    var productCode: String
    var UPCCode: String
    var servingSize: String
    var servingPerContainer: String
    var amountPerServing: [String]
    var percentageDailyValue: String
    var description: [String]
    var suggestedUse: String
    var otherIngredients: [String]
    var warning: [String]

    #if DEBUG
    static let example = ItemList(
        id: UUID(),
        status: "in-stock",
        quantity: 10,
        name: "Doctor's Best, Vitamin D3, 25 mcg (1,000 IU), 180 Softgels",
        price: 4.98,
        image: "753950002098.front",
        moreImage: ["753950002098.back"],
        productCode: "DRB-00209",
        UPCCode: "753950002098",
        servingSize: "1 Softgel",
        servingPerContainer: "180 servings",
        amountPerServing: ["Vitamin D3: 25 mcg (1000 IU)"],
        percentageDailyValue: "125%",
        description: ["Empty, Empty"],
        suggestedUse: "Adult Use: Take 1 softgel daily with food, or as recommended by a nutritionally-informed physician.",
        otherIngredients: ["Extra virgin olive oil; softgel capsule (bovine gelatin; glycerin; purified water)"],
        warning: ["Store in a cool dry place."]
    )
    #endif
}
```

**JSON file (validated) (file name: productsTest.json)**

```
[
    {
        "id": "EF1CC5BB-4785-4D8E-AB98-5FA4E00B6A66",
        "category": "SUPPLEMENT",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "EDCD038C-036F-4C40-826F-61C88CD84DDD",
                "status" : "in-stock",
                "quantity" : 10,
                "name": "Doctor's Best, Vitamin D3, 25 mcg (1,000 IU), 180 Softgels",
                "price" : 4.98,
                "image" : "753950002098.front",
                "moreImage": ["753950002098.back"],
                "productCode" : "DRB-00209",
                "UPCCode" : "753950002098",
                "servingSize" : "1 Softgel",
                "servingPerContainer" : "180 servings",
                "amountPerServing" : ["Vitamin D3: 25 mcg (1000 IU)"],
                "percentageDailyValue" : "125%",
                "description" : ["Empty, Empty"],
                "suggestedUse" : "Adult Use: Take 1 softgel daily with food, or as recommended by a nutritionally-informed physician.",
                "otherIngredients" : ["Extra virgin olive oil; softgel capsule (bovine gelatin; glycerin; purified water)"],
                "warning" : ["Store in a cool dry place."]
                
            },
            {
                "id": "36A7CC40-18C1-48E5-BCD8-3B42D43BEAEE",
                "status" : "in-stock",
                "quantity" : 5,
                "name": "Now Foods, High Potency Vitamin D-3, 50 mcg (2000 IU), 120 Softgels",
                "price" : 4.26,
                "image" : "733739003676.front",
                "moreImage": ["733739003676.back"],
                "productCode" : "NOW-00367",
                "UPCCode" : "753950002098",
                "servingSize" : "1 Softgel",
                "servingPerContainer" : "120 servings",
                "amountPerServing" : ["Vitamin D4: 50 mcg (2000 IU)"],
                "percentageDailyValue" : "250%",
                "description" : ["Empty, Empty"],
                "suggestedUse" : "Take 1 softgel daily with a meal.",
                "otherIngredients" : ["Extra virgin olive oil and softgel capsule (bovine gelatin; water; glycerin)., Not manufactured with yeast; wheat; gluten; soy; corn; milk; egg; fish or shellfish ingredients. Produced in a GMP facility that processes other ingredients containing these allergens."],
                "warning" : ["For adults only, Consult physician if pregnant/nursing; taking medication; or have a medical condition. Keep out of reach of children, Natural color variation may occur in this product, Store in a cool, dry place after opening."]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3D97FAB4-50AC-40FC-9BF0-3F46BB6A92F5",
        "category": "ELECTRONICS",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "empty",
                "status" : "empty",
                "quantity" : 0,
                "name": "empty",
                "price" : 0.00,
                "image" : "empty",
                "moreImage": ["empty"],
                "productCode" : "empty",
                "UPCCode" : "empty",
                "servingSize" : "empty",
                "servingPerContainer" : "empty",
                "amountPerServing" : ["empty"],
                "percentageDailyValue" : "empty",
                "description" : ["empty"],
                "suggestedUse" : "empty",
                "otherIngredients" : ["empty"],
                "warning" : ["empty"] 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Crash Console Report**

```
...
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [4837]

Application Specific Information:
JOCO/DecodeJson.swift:23: Fatal error: Failed to decode products.json from app bundle.
...
```

Comment: **Don't use `try ?`**!  You are throwing away the very informative error that will tell you why your json couldn't be decoded. Use a plain `try`, `catch` the error and print it. Can you tell me where you got this code?  I continually see questions here where people are using `try ?` with json decoding. I want to find the source of this nonsense

Comment: Wow, thanks for saving me, I had the same issue. Since you asked, the source of the try? madness is Paul Hudson, who had it as part of his article on how to build a JSON decoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pretty much never use `try?` - It simply discards errors. You should, at the very least, catch and print the error if you can't handle it in a better way; Then at least you know what is going wrong.

Changing your JSON decoding to:

```
extension Bundle {
    
    func decode<x: Decodable>(_ type: x.Type, from filename: String) -> x? {
        guard let json = url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil) else {
            print("Failed to locate \(filename) in app bundle.")
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: json)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let result = try decoder.decode(x.self, from: jsonData)
            return result
        } catch {
            print("Failed to load and decode JSON \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

gives you the error

> Failed to load and decode JSON dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "items", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Attempted to decode UUID from invalid UUID string.", underlyingError: nil))

which points you straight to the problem - The first `item` (Index 0) in the second element of the outer array (Index 1) has an invalid `id` - And sure enough, it has an `id` of "empty" - Which cannot be converted to a UUID.  So, either fix the data or perhaps change the type of `id` to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of queue of edits, i repost it with additions (from [Reading in a JSON File Using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410881/reading-in-a-json-file-using-swift)):

Using it like:

```
let data = loadJson(file: "translations")
```

**Swift 4.x and 5.x using Decodable**

```
struct ResponseData: Decodable {
    var person: [Person]
}
struct Person : Decodable {
    var name: String
    var age: String
    var employed: String
}

func loadJson(filename fileName: String) -> [Person]? {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let jsonData = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)
            return jsonData.person
        } catch {
            print("error:\(error)")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func loadJson(filename fileName: String) -> [String: AnyObject]? {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
                return dictionary
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error!! Unable to parse  \(fileName).json")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

P.S. If u want to use it to load file with any extension, change func loadJson body from `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json")` to `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: nil)` and use it like:

```
let data = loadJson(file: "translations.any_extension")
```

P.P.S. Also, for more readability refactor with renaming func `loadJson` to `decode`