# Swift: How to pass a codable type as a function input to encode or decode json

Tags: json, swift, codable

I would like to make a helper function which takes input of encodable/decodable type in order to encode or decode json. I have tried

```swift
static func loadCache<T:Decodable>(fileName:String, type:T)throws->T{
        let data = try FileManager.loadCache(fileName: fileName)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
```

Using the function

```swift
let products = try loadCache(fileName: Product.cacheFileName(), type: [Product])
```

I am getting error `Type '[Product].Type' cannot conform to 'Decodable'`

what is the correct way to pass this to a function
Thanks

Comment: you can have to use T.type and [Product].self but you can not use files like this

Comment: you can use files like this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410881/reading-in-a-json-file-using-swift

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali FileManager.loadCache is my own custom extension which generates data. I should mention that in the question i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. Your syntax is just slightly incorrect. You want to pass the type as a value, not a value of the type, so this is the signature you need:

```
static func loadCache<T:Decodable>(fileName:String, type: T.Type) throws -> T{
                                                           ^^^^^
```

Swift requires that you be very explicit about passing types as values. It requires adding `.self`:

```
let products = try loadCache(fileName: Product.cacheFileName(),
                             type: [Product].self)
                                            ^^^^^
```